# unable to install tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, install.packages

i am trying to install tidyverse by running `install.packages("tidyverse")`. it is asking whether i need to install from source or not. i choose No but it is throwing the following error.

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'processx' 3.5.3 is being loaded, but >= 3.6.1 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'callr'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library/callr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'callr' is not available for package 'reprex'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library/reprex'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘reprex’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency 'reprex' is not available for package 'tidyverse'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.3/library/tidyverse'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

this is the session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3
```

i looked at [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-install-devtools-need-to-update-processx-version/34639/2) and reinstalled Rtools. i tried installing from github also. but it is not working. how do i avoid these errors and install **tidyverse**. i am doing this on my work machine so it takes some time to request updated version of Rtools.

Comment: update the processx package and try again

Comment: i ran `update.packages()` and then `install.packages("tidyverse")` but still got the same error

Comment: if you installed a new package, how are you still getting `namespace 'processx' 3.5.3 is being loaded, but >= 3.6.1`

Comment: even after running `update.packages()`, it is still loading `other attached packages:
[1] processx_3.5.3`. i got that version details from sessionInfo()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the above mentioned [source](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-install-devtools-need-to-update-processx-version/34639) i forgot to try the `options(pkgType = "binary")` option. once i run that line i am able to install `tidyverse`.